# Struggling with identifying element using multiple params

Tags: xpath, web, automation

fairly new to xpaths.
I have the below element and I need an xpath to identify it using its ID/xpath and that it has the disabled node in it.

```
<button class="mr-2 st-crudactionbar__button ng-star-inserted waves-effect waves-float" id="crudactionbar_remove_button" disabled="">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

So tried:

```
//*[@id="crudactionbar_remove_button"] and @disabled =''
```

or

```
(//*[contains(@class,'crudactionbar__button')])[4] and @disabled =''
```

Hopefully you get the idea of what I am trying to do. look for that element and that it also contains the disabled node. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the conditions related to the element (button) must go to the same square brackets:

```
//button[contains(@class, 'crudactionbar__button') and @disabled='']
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. As in my original xpath, how do i add the [4] so it picks the fourth item into this xpath? I thought like this but it does not work: //button[contains(@class, 'crudactionbar__button')[4] and @disabled='']

Comment: Ignore this. Its sorted. Thanks for your help